# How to write internal column names to host

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, powershell, column, internal-name

At the moment I m trying to use this:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

#Get Web
$web = Get-SPWeb http://...

#Get List
$list = $web.Lists["List1"]

$list.DefaultView.ViewFields | Write-Host
```

And then I get this:

```
LinkTitle
Status
h48p
```

But I need the internal title from the column. These are the static names.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below:

```
$list.fields | select Title, InternalName, StaticName
```

**References**:

1. [SharePoint–Finding Column Display and Internal Names](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/10/sharepointfinding-column-display-and.html).
2. [Get List Fields in SharePoint using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/04/get-list-fields-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html).

**Additional**:

You can get the internal name of columns from SharePoint UI as wellby following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But thats not what i needed. I only need the "Title" of the columns from the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer i needed:

```
foreach ($names in $list.DefaultView.ViewFields)
{
    $list.Fields.GetField($names).Title
}
```

Now I get only the title from columns of the default view.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?  Or is this more information for your question?  If it's the latter, it would be better to update your question rather than posting an update as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code, I just tested this in SharePoint 2013, Kindly update with the site url, list name, view name in the below code.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

$site = Get-SPSite "YOUR SITE URL"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists["YOUR LIST NAME"]
foreach ($view in $list.Views) #Get all views in lists 
    { 

         if($view.Title -eq "YOUR VIEW NAME"){
            $spView = $web.GetViewFromUrl($view.Url) #Grab views URL 
            Write-Host "View Name: " $view.Title  ##View title 
            Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------" 
            Write-Host "Field Name | Field Type | Field Internal Name " 
            Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------" 
            foreach ($spField in $spView.ViewFields) #Loop through all view URLs and get Fields (columns) 
            { 
                foreach ($field in $list.Fields) #Get all fields in lists 
                { 
                    if($spField -eq $field.Title) #if field in lists equals field in views 
                    { 
                        Write-Host $spField " | " $field.Type " | " $field.InternalName -ForegroundColor Green #Write out each field (column)                         
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------" 
            Write-Host " " 
        }
    }     

Remove-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

Comment: Did this answer, help you?